# Certain open subsets of $L^1$ for $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on a metric space $X$, let $B$ be a Borel subset of $X$ of positive $\mu$-measure.  Then when does the set
$$
\left\{
I_K g:\, g \in L^1_{\mu}(X)
\right\}\subseteq L^1_{\mu}(X)
$$
define a subset of $L^1_{\mu}(X)$ with non-empty interior (besides when $K=X$)?

More generally(ish), what about when $I_K$ is replaced by a strictly positive $\mu$-integrable function?

Comment: When you say 'with open interior' do you mean 'with non-empty interior'?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I made the edits accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subset is the range of the multiplication operator (with multiplier $I_K$ or any other measurable function). In particular, it is a subspace. As such, it is open if and only if it equals $L^1_\mu(X)$. For a multiplication operator with nonnegative multiplier this is the case if and only if the multiplier is bounded away from zero, i.e., there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $f\geq c$ a.e. If $f=1_K$, then this is equivalent to $\mu(X\setminus K)=0$.

Comment: This is very interesting!  Do you happen to have a reference to this topic?  I would be interested in reading more.

Comment: Which topic exactly? Weidmann's book on Linear operators in Hilbert spaces is a good reference for operator theory in general.

Comment: Mostly on the multiplication operator stuff precisely.

Comment: I think Weidmann is good for that (I don't have my copy handy right now, so I can't say for sure).

Comment: Right, and so if in particular, $f$ can never be the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu\ll\mu$ if $\nu$ is finite and $\mu$ is non-finite (since otherwise $\int 1 d\nu = \int f d\mu \geq \int c d\mu = \infty$)?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I was thinking, if instead we consider $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ f_n g:g \in L^1_{\mu}(X)\}$ then this is a dense subset of $\{fg: g \in L^1_{\mu}(X)\}$, if each $0\leq f_n<f$ and converge monotonically increasingly to $f$ no?  *Point: So we can avoid the constrain $f_n>0$ by considering a sequence which is eventually bounded away from 0$*?

Answer (score 2):

Answer for the first part:  A necessary and sufficient condition is $\mu (X\setminus K)=0$. First assume that $\mu$ is a  finite measure. One way is obvious. If  $\mu (X\setminus K)>0$ then $I_Kg+\frac 1 n I_{X\setminus K}$ is  sequence converging to  $I_Kg$ but no term of this sequence belongs to the given set. This means the set has  no interior points. The extension of this argument to the sigma finite case is straightforward.